# make bash array from incrementally adding another array

Tags: arrays, bash

So if I have a bash array:

```
ar=( "one" "two" "three" "four")
```

What is the best way to make a new array such that it looks like this:

```
ar-new=( "one" "one two" "one two three" "one two three four" )
```

I cooked up something that use a for loop inside a for loop and using `seq`. Is there a better/more elegant way to accomplish this?

Comment: dump whatever you 'cooked' and we shall see how to improve it

Comment: what actual problem are you solving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way:

```
for ((i=1; i<=${#ar[@]}; i++ ))
do
    ar_new+=("${ar[*]:0:$i} ")
done
```

Comment: Sweet exactly what I was looking for (some manipulation with bash variable itself)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what, exactly, you are trying to accomplish, you can do it in one loop without any external commands.

Using an arithmetic `for` loop:

```
typeset -a ar
ar=("one" "two" "three" "four")
typeset -a ar_new=()
p=""
for (( i=0; i < ${#ar[@]}; ++i )); do
    p="$p${p:+ }${ar[$i]}"
    ar_new[$i]="$p"
done
```

Using a string `for` loop loop (might not work for large arrays?, might be slower for large arrays):

```
typeset -a ar
ar=("one" "two" "three" "four")
typeset -a ar_new=()
p=""
for s in "${ar[@]}"; do
    p="$p${p:+ }$s"
    ar_new=("${ar_new[@]}" "$p")
done
```